# How to scroll an element into horizontal center?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a bunch of pictures within a showcase and Whenever any picture is pressed
I would like it to scroll to the horizontal center

I tried `.scrollIntoView()` but the problem was that the entire page was scrolling with it instead of just the showcase
I've managed to use `scrollTo()` but it doesn't seem to perfectly align the image to the center:

[image]

Can someone please tell me why this is happening? I even took margin and width into calculation
(I'm open to changing my approach if it achieves the ultimate goal)

```js
const showcase=document.querySelector(".showcase")
const move_img=(by)=>{

  const img=showcase.querySelector("img")
  const style=window.getComputedStyle(img);
  showcase.scrollTo({
    top: 0,
    left: (parseInt(style.width) + parseInt(style.marginLeft)) * (by - 1 ),
    behavior: "smooth",
  });
  
  /* 
    showcase.children[index].scrollIntoView({
            behavior: 'smooth',
            block: 'nearest',
            inline: 'center'
        });
    */

}

Array.from(showcase.children).forEach((child, index) => {

  child.onclick=()=>{move_img(index, true)}
});
```

```css
:root{
  --main_pic_width:30rem;
  --showcase_height:5rem;
  --showcase_division:3;
  --showcase_gap:1rem;
}

.showcase{
  width:calc( var(--main_pic_width) + var(--showcase_gap));
  height:var(--showcase_height);
  background:gray;
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow-y:hidden;
  overflow-x:auto;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
  scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
  }
.showcase::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none;  /* Safari and Chrome */
}

.showcase img{
  width:calc( var(--main_pic_width)/var(--showcase_division) - var(--showcase_gap));
  background-color:black;
  margin-left:var(--showcase_gap);
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="showcase">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_forest.jpg" />
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_5terre.jpg"/>
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_mountains.jpg"/>
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_lights.jpg"/>
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_5terre.jpg"/>
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_forest.jpg"/>
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_mountains.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the position to scroll to using `offsetLeft` and `offsetWidth`.

```js
const showcase = document.querySelector(".showcase");
showcase.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.matches('img')) 
    showcase.scroll({left: e.target.offsetLeft - (showcase.offsetWidth - e.target.offsetWidth) / 2, behavior: 'smooth'});
});
```

```css
:root{
  --main_pic_width:30rem;
  --showcase_height:5rem;
  --showcase_division:3;
  --showcase_gap:1rem;
}

.showcase{
  width:calc( var(--main_pic_width) + var(--showcase_gap));
  height:var(--showcase_height);
  background:gray;
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow-y:hidden;
  overflow-x:auto;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
  scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
  }
.showcase::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none;  /* Safari and Chrome */
}

.showcase img{
  width:calc( var(--main_pic_width)/var(--showcase_division) - var(--showcase_gap));
  background-color:black;
  margin-left:var(--showcase_gap);
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="showcase">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_forest.jpg" />
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_5terre.jpg"/>
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_mountains.jpg"/>
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_lights.jpg"/>
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_5terre.jpg"/>
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_forest.jpg"/>
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_mountains.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Unmitigated's answer works but for some reason it didn't work in production
perhaps some margin or padding I missed?

regardless I found the solution:

```js
const showcase=document.querySelector(".showcase")
const move_img=(by)=>{

  const img=showcase.querySelector("img")
  const style=window.getComputedStyle(img);
  showcase.scrollTo({
    top: 0,
    left: (parseInt(style.width) + parseInt(style.marginLeft) + parseInt(style.marginRight)) * (by - 1 ),
    behavior: "smooth",
  });
}

Array.from(showcase.children).forEach((child, index) => {

  child.onclick=()=>{move_img(index, true)}
});
```

```css
:root{
  --main_pic_width:30rem;
  --showcase_height:5rem;
  --showcase_division:3;
  --showcase_gap:1rem;
}



.showcase{
  
  width:var(--main_pic_width);
  height:var(--showcase_height);
  background:gray;
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow-y:hidden;
  overflow-x:auto;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
  scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
  }
.showcase::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none;  /* Safari and Chrome */
}

.showcase img{
  height: 100%;
    width: calc( (var(--main_pic_width) - var(--showcase_gap) * var(--showcase_division) * 2) / var(--showcase_division));
  margin: 0 var(--showcase_gap);
  object-fit: contain;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="showcase">
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_forest.jpg" /><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_5terre.jpg"/><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_mountains.jpg"/><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_lights.jpg"/><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_5terre.jpg"/><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_forest.jpg"/><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_mountains.jpg"/> -->
</div>
```

Also the reason all the `<img>` tags are in a single line is because adding a newline creates a space in between 2 images which messes up the calculation